# How to set the list of words to be in the same line in latex

Tags: latex

I have a list of words of abbreviations with their complete names.

What I need is to make the second column with same line regardless the size of abbreviation in the first column, here is the code of the latex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{verbatim} % multi line comment pkg
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{cases}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} 


\begin{document}

NE \ \ \ Network 

UN \ \ \ Unite

USA \ \ \ Unite state of America

\end{document}
```

For example, in the above code, the abbreviation of USA is bigger than others, so the second column in that line will be moved also little bit,  so what I need is to make the second column with same line regardless the size of the abbreviation

Comment: Suggest you use the `tabular` environment. See also https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables#Creating_a_simple_table_in_LaTeX

Comment: Is it possible. for example, to replace the ` \ \ \ \` in each line by another thing to do that ?

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, have a look at the acro or acronym package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, have a look at the `acro`, `acronym` or even the `glossaries` package.

A short example using `acronym`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{verbatim} % multi line comment pkg
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{cases}
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} 

\usepackage{acronym}



\begin{document}


\begin{acronym}[USA]
\acro{NE}{Network}
\acro{UN}{Unite}
\acro{USA}{United States}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image]